# IOS UITableViewCell De-select a view once selected and returned to page

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

How can I deselect a cell when returning to a view?

I have an orange down state which is applied to a cell when selected - the cell navigates to a modal view when clicked - when i click back button the cell is still selected.

I have tried applying this code -

```
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

to my cellForRowAtIndexPath method - but it doesn't do anything!

**Update** - Having done a bit of research - It appears Ive missed some valuable information out of this question! - my table view is a UITableView embedded in a View Controller - not a UITableViewController - so it sounds like it doesnt have the available methods which are required for the suggestions so far..

Answer (score 1):

You should not call `deselectRowAtIndexPath` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

you can do this in viewWillAppear

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear: animated];

    NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [tableViewObj indexPathForSelectedRow];
    if (selectedIndexPath != nil) {
        [tableViewObj deselectRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Or you can write in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` as well

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
       [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath  animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: sorry @Bhumeshwer katre - Ive just updated my question below - by table view is embedded in a UIView so it doesnt have the appear method.

Comment: @Dancer then you can deselect row at `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method. Its already in answer.

Comment: thanks @Bhumeshwer katre - that disables the selected state altogether - i'm actually after the selected state being applied when clicking but removed when returning to the page - is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `UITableViewController`'s `clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear` property.

Comment: thanks @Zydeco - my table view is embedded in a UIView - which method would I apply the clearselectiononviewwillappear?

Comment: if you're not using a UITableViewController, maybe you can deselect the row after the modal view appears

Answer (score 0):

This is the right approach

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
   [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath  animated:NO]; // first line in this method

   // rest of code 

}
```